# Can pagewidth depend dynamically on user's zoom/scale, on tablets?

Tags: javascript, android, html

**Part 1:** *(maybe solved, see part 2)*
Using meta viewport width=devicewidth locks you to a fixed page width.
I instead want the users' zoom to control font size, but always adjust the pagewidth to
fit in the zoomed viewport width. When you resize a browser window on desktop, it actually
does this (reflows your paragraphs to the changed width).
  But default on tablets/mobiles, is that you pan around a fixed page-width.

**Background:** On mobile/tablets, I want to fit the contents/paragraphs to the user's viewport, so he doesn't have to 'pan around' the view. But I still want zoom to be useful: I just want it to scale the text. The default behaviour, where zooming to increase font size, also forces you to continously 'pan' left and right to read every paragraph, in my belief is useless. Though I now appear to have achieved it by adapting viewport-content-width continously, by my lack of experience I'm not sure if I've 'just achieved a kludge'.

**Part 2:** I've figured out a sort of solution myself. So.. are there better/more robust ways to do this/cross-platform?
  I added this javascript event listener, to just update the viewport width dynamically, on window resize, and set viewport to same width as 'window.innerWidth':

(it assumes you set id 'theviewport' on your meta viewport tag.)

```
window.addEventListener( "resize", function(e) {
  var mv = document.getElementById('theviewport');
  mv.setAttribute('content','width='+window.innerWidth);
});
```

but is  this a reasonable way?

Comment: Are you requesting the community to answer if your Javascript is reasonable, or "Can pagewidth depend dynamically on user's zoom/scale, on tablets"?

Comment: Both: 'what is the most sensible way to achieve this? (e.g. the javascript)', and secondly: is this generally viable across platforms, or is the goal brittle and better abandoned?
  In the meantime, I'm getting experience using the solution (on an android samsung), and I feel this is something a lot of people would want to use, when targetting mobile platform: Your user can use his zoom to control reading font/rendering size, but he avoids the questionable "panning around a postage stamp" crap, that mobile scaling usually results in.

Comment: Doesn't `em` create sizes based on total screen width?

Comment: it might, but I want paragraphs to wrap inside the visible viewport extent.